# Limits of compositions of functions with non-continuous outer function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, continuity

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_of_compositions_of_functions):

Suppose
$$
\lim_{y \to b} f(y) = c \text{ and }\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = b
$$

Then $$\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = c$$

IF:

1. $f$ is continuous at $b$, OR
2. $g$ does not take the value $b$ near $a$ (that is, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|g(x)-b|>0$)

They then provide an example that satisfies Neither of these requirements:

$$f(x)=g(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if } x\neq 0 \\ 1 & \text{if } x=0 \end{cases}$$

My question: is there a case of a non-continuous $f(x)$, which allows the application of the rule, because $g(x)$ satisfies the 2nd requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x$ if $x\ne 1$ and $=0$ if $x=1$, and $g(x)=x$.

Then, $f$ is not continuous at $x=1$ and $g$ does not take $1$ if $x\ne 1$.

Since $f(g(x))=x$ if $x\ne1$,
$$
\lim_{x\to1, x\ne 1}f(g(x)) = 1.
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132637/discussion-on-answer-by-i-h-limits-of-compositions-of-functions-with-non-continu).