# How find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))$ when $f$ is not continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits

First let me give a bit background. We have a standard theorem:

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = b$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to b}f(x) = L$ and $f(x)$ is *continuous* at $b$, then we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x)) = L$.

In this theorem the continuity of $f$ at $a$ is crucial.

**Now my question begins:**

We have many standard limits that we use. For example, there are two standard limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} = na^{n-1} \text{ for }n\in\mathbb Q, \text{ and } \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1.
$$

By using such limits we deduce, for example,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+2x^2)^{1/3}-1}{2x^2} = 1/3, \text{ and } \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sin x}-1}{\sin x} = 1
$$

How are we able to deduce these? Certainly we can't use the theorem above as in these cases $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

Can we generalise it something like this:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{e^{g(x)} - 1}{g(x)} = 1,
$$
if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$?

Comment: What these limits are telling you is exactly that if, for example, you define $f(x)$ to be the function which is equal to $\frac{x^n - a^n}{x - a}$ if $x \neq a$ and equal to $na^{n-1}$ if $x = a$, then this function *is* continuous at $a$. Then you can apply the theorem just fine. In this example it's particularly clear because $\frac{x^n - a^n}{x - a} = x^{n-1} + ax^{n-2} + \dots + a^{n-1}$ is just a polynomial but the same idea applies to the second example.

Comment: Perhaps-I might be mistaken but that is my insight from your question-you are confusing the notion of a function *defined* at a certain point with the function *having a limit* there. Your initial function can have a limit where it is not defined, and then, as Qiacochu's comment shows, you can "extend" that initial function to one that is continuous.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh! You are so correct. Thanks! If you add this comment as an answer. I shall accept it.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Yes, I didn't get the idea of extending the function to make it continuous. It is helpful.

Comment: If you do get $f$ that is discontinuous at $g(a)$, then the result of $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x))$ will depend on $g$. If $g$ is constant around $x = a$, then so is $f \circ g$, so the limit will be $f(g(a))$. If $g$ approaches a constant $b$ from below (i.e. $g(x) \to b$, but $g(x) < b$ for $x$ close to $x = a$, but not necessarily at $a$), then $\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = \lim_{x \to b^-} f(x)$. A similar thing if $g$ approaches from above. All sorts of things can happen without continuity, but it's often not too difficult to work out if you think things through carefully.

Comment: The result does not need continuity of $f$ at $b$. If $g(x) \to b$ and $g(x) \neq b$ as $x\to a$ and $f(x) \to L$ as $x\to b$ then $f(g(x)) \to L$ as $x\to a$. Continuity is needed when we need to interchange limit operation with functional operation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No. Please read the answer of bjorn93. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342127/limit-laws-for-composite-functions

Comment: With continuity as in your question we have $L=f(b)$ and the theorem then reads as follows: if $g(x) \to b$ as $x\to a$ and $f$ is continuous at $b$ then $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) = f\left(\lim_{x\to a} g(x)\right) $ so that the operation $\lim_{x\to a} $ and functional operation $f$ can be interchanged.

Comment: The two versions of limit laws related to composite functions are those which I have mentioned in my comments. One is without any continuity and other is with continuity. Both are valid and can be applied.

Comment: The counterexample in bjorn93 answer does not apply to the theorem mentioned in my first comment. Perhaps you should have a look at the condition $g(x) \neq b$ as $x\to a$ which is important as well and not satisfied by bjorn93 counterexample. Note also that this condition is not needed in the second theorem which uses continuity of $f$ at $b$.

Comment: The examples in your question are all justified using theorem in my first comment. In particular your last result holds provided we have additional hypothesis $g(x) \neq 0$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: I am convinced. You are correct. Thanks for the help!